# Lightswitch V2: Datagrid Columns not auto-resizing

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

Hi I have noticed that in Lightswitch v2 (Visual Studio 2012), the Auto Size mode for data grid columns doesn't seem to be working. That is, the columns do not re-size to accommodate my content. If I remember correctly, this used to work in Visual Studio Lightswitch v1...

Does anyone know how to make the data grid columns re-size to accommodate content in Lightswitch v2?

Note that I am able to manually stretch my columns - this is not what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, they have changed that feature to improve speed and reduce any annoying glitches.

Preferably, I would also like to see the columns stretch to fit all information within a cell, but I don't think it is currently possible. I would consult the dev's on this issue; it may be temporary.